# c std::vector splitting into two

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, split, runtime

Is there an easy and run-time efficient way to take a `std::vector<>` in c++ and split it in half into two other vectors?

Because right now I'm doing this:

```
std::vector<> v1, v2;
for(int i = 0; i < vector.size(); i++)
{
    if(i < vector.size()/2) v1.push_back(vector[i]);
    else v2.push_back(vector[i]);
}
```

which runs in `O(n)` time and this is an operation I have to perform quite frequently. So is there a better way?

Comment: Just use iterators to refer to the different halves without actually splitting them.

Comment: If you need to do that a lot, perhaps using a different container would be a better fit for your algorithms?

Comment: If you need to do that frequently, are you facing a design issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to split a vector into two smaller arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9811235/608639)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you really need 2 vectors, and you can't use GMan's suggestion in the comments:

```
// where v1 is your original vector
std::vector<T> v2(
    std::make_move_iterator(v1.begin() + v1.size()/2),
    std::make_move_iterator(v1.end()));
v1.erase(v1.begin() + v1.size()/2, v1.end());
```

It's still O(n), but you can't do any better than that.

If you need to keep the original vector separate:

```
std::vector<T> v2(v1.begin(), v1.begin() + v1.size()/2),
               v3(v1.begin() + v1.size()/2, v1.end());
```

Comment: Why do you need the v1.end() in the second parameter for both calls?

Comment: @user1855952: It designates the end of the range which you which you want to copy or erase, whatever the case may be.

Comment: You could improve this by using `std::make_move_iterator(v1.begin())` and `std::make_move_iterator(v1.end())` to fill `v2`

Comment: @JonathanWakely: Good call. Done.