# Splitting an STL list?

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl

I have a circular linked list that looks something like this:

`4 -> 3 -> 2 -> 5 -> 0 -> 1 -> beginning`

I want to split this list into two segments, reverse one of the segments, and then rejoin the list. Something like this:

Split, an O(1) operation
`4 ** 3 -> 2 -> 5 ** 0 -> 1 -> beginning`

Reverse, an O(n) operation
`0 ** 3 -> 2 -> 5 ** 4 -> 1 -> beginning`

Rejoin, an O(1) operation
`0 -> 3 -> 2 -> 5 -> 4 -> 1 -> beginning`

The STL does not appear to have a circular linked list, but I'm hoping I can get away with representing the list as a (forward) list. This, requires:
* A way to split the lists into sublists
* A way to merge the lists together

Merging the sublists together should be easy using [std::list::splice](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/splice/), and it should be an O(1) operation. Yay!

However, I can't find a good O(1) way to split the lists into sublists. [One approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13887979/c-stdvector-splitting-into-two) is to use iterators, but I don't think that works in my case because the sublist goes off the end of the list and resumes at the beginning of the list.

Is there an efficient way to implement this algorithm using the STL? Or should I just give up and write my own circular linked list library?

Thanks!

Comment: If your total operation is O(N), why do you want your split operation to be O(1)? As per this link there is no standard implementation of a circular linked list.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/947489/does-a-standard-implementation-of-a-circular-list-exist-for-c

Comment: Ultimately, I want to make my program as fast as reasonably possible. O(N) split + O(N) reverse is going to be slower than O(1) split + O(N) reverse.

Also, I'm pretty sure I can get away with always reversing the shortest sublist, so hopefully N is small in that case.

Comment: Is this for TSP? You may want a two-level tree instead of a linked list, which reduces the running time to O(sqrt(n)) without the big constant factor of binary trees (O(log(n))).

Comment: @JohnSaxton I don't think the split operation can be an O(1) operation in a linked list. This is because you first need to reach the 'splitting node' and then transfer the 'next' pointers. This 'reaching' operation is an O(N) operation.

Comment: @JohnSaxton how about O(0) for splitting, don't split your list, just do a logical split using a list of const iterators to the beginning of each sublist, then stop when you reach the next iterator :) and for reverse, you can do reflection-swap around the pivot (which doesn't exist in case the size of the chosen sublist is odd

Comment: @JohnSaxton "O(N) split + O(N) ... is going to be slower" N+N vs 1+ 100*N for example.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure how helpful this is, but here it is:

```
template<typename I>
void inner(I b, I e)
{
    std::reverse(b, e);  // l = {4 5 2 3 0 1}
}

template<typename L, typename I>
void outer(L& l, I b, I e)
{
    l.splice(l.begin(), l, e, l.end());  // l = {0 1 4 3 2 5}
    std::reverse(l.begin(), b);          // l = {4 1 0 3 2 5}
}

int main ()
{
    std::list<int> t, l{4, 3, 2, 5, 0, 1};
    std::cout << l << std::endl;

    auto b = l.begin(), e = l.begin();
    std::advance(b, 1);
    std::advance(e, 4);
    bool in = true;

    in ? inner(b, e) : outer(l, b, e);
    std::cout << l << std::endl;
}
```

There are two options:

- reverse the *inner* part of the list (`3 2 5`)
- reverse the *outer* part (`0 1 -> 4`)

and you might want to reverse the shorter one, but you'll have to count for this, which is linear-time. I have written two separate functions `inner,outer` for these two tasks.

`inner` is very simple (nothing but a wrapper) and working as expected. However, `outer` is leaving the list in a state that is equivalent to the expected modulo some rotation (circular shift). If you are modelling a circular list, this should be fine. But if you want the output exactly as in your example, you'll have to count again, to find the right point where to rotate. I would avoid this, as it is linear-time.

Note that no splitting is actually needed, because reversal is in-place. Also, operation

```
l.splice(l.begin(), l, e, l.end());
```

is constant-time.

Check [live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/df4ed99cc193a0e1).