# What is the purpose of std::make_move_iterator()?

Tags: c++, optimization, vector, iterator

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> foo = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
    std::vector<int> v1(foo.begin(), foo.begin() + foo.size()/2);
    std::vector<int> v2(std::make_move_iterator(foo.begin() + foo.size()/2),
                      std::make_move_iterator(foo.end()));

    for (int i: v1)
        std::cout << i << " ";
    std::cout << std::endl;
    for (int j: v2)
        std::cout << j << " ";

    return 0;
}
```

```
$ ./a.out 
1 2 3 
4 5 6
```

I am able to split a vector with or without `make_move_iterator()` but I read [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13887979/c-stdvector-splitting-into-two#comment19132177_13888008) suggesting that using this function is "an improvement." What advantage does it provide?

Comment: do you know what it means to move something?

Comment: This is unrelated to iterators. Consider `int x = 1, y = std::move(x);`. Moving an `int` is same as copying it, but there are types for which moving is different from copying. E.g. try to rewrite your example to split a vector *of vectors* (moving a (nested) vector is different from copying).

Answer (score 3):

`std::make_move_iterator` makes a `std::move_iterator` from the given input iterator.

The `std::move_iterator` is the same as the original iterator, except that it returns a rvalue reference instead of a lvalue reference when dereferenced, permitting the referenced element of the range to be *moved*-from by whoever dereferences the iterator.

So it would allow a `std::vector<T>` constructor to move-construct its `T` elements from the provided iterator range's elements, rather than having to copy-construct them.

As always, for non-class types such as `int`, moving and copying is exactly the same thing, so there is no benefit for `std::vector<int>` at all.

Answer (score 2):

Do you need `foo` after the copying? If not the elements can be moved from. That means, if the elements manage some resource then that resource can be stolen from the element rather than copied. For example if you had a vector of `std::string` then it would be a matter of copying a single pointer to the character array rather than copying each character individually to a new array.

"Normal" iterators return a reference to the element when dereferenced. A `std::move_iterator` returns a r-value reference that can be moved from.

However, for `int` elements that makes no difference, because an `int` manages no resource. Its just a value. Moving from an `int` is effectively identical to copying it.

---

> What is the purpose of std::make_move_iterator()?

In your code? None.

In the answer you link to? In general the elements of type `T` might be moveable, then using the `std::move_iterator` turns a potentially expensive copy into a potentially cheap move. This is only ok because the original elements are not needed anymore. Using the `std::move_iterator` does not affect the vectors size. The elements will still be there, though in a moved-from state.